# write.txt constantly adds col.names when col.names=FALSE is specified

Tags: r, header, write.table

I tried to write a dataframe into a txt file without heading, but it kept adding column names. When I opened the file directly from the drive, it has 21 rows without the heading, but when I opened the file using read.delim(), I can see headers with some symbols.

Here is the code

```
write.table(trans_sequence, file="mytxtout.txt", sep=";", col.names =FALSE, row.names = FALSE, 
            quote = FALSE)
```

When I retrieved the data using read.delim, it looks like below. It should have 21 rows, but it made the top row a column name, making 20 rows. The first row should be like this
2745;9;2;HbA1c;LDL;C;Tests
But it created a header instead

```
read.delim("mytxtout.txt")

                   X2745.9.2.HbA1c.LDL.C.Tests
1                 10433;9;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
2                        13601;0;1;LDL-C Tests
3                        13601;6;1;LDL-C Tests
4                 36127;2;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
5                     36127;5;1;Blood Pressure
6                 36127;9;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
7                36127;10;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
8                  54881;9;2;HbA1c;LDL-C Tests
9                 59650;0;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
10                59650;3;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
11                       66741;0;1;LDL-C Tests
12                       72772;3;1;LDL-C Tests
13 77618;2;3;BMI;BMI Percentile;Blood Pressure
14                77618;3;2;BMI;BMI Percentile
15                               81397;4;1;BMI
16                81397;6;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
17                81397;9;2;BMI;Blood Pressure
18                               81397;9;1;BMI
19 83520;6;3;BMI;BMI Percentile;Blood Pressure
20                      85178;10;1;LDL-C Tests
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to specify `header = FALSE` for  `read.delim()` as well

Comment: Yes, it is not writing column names, it is reading the first row as column names in `read.delim()`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. When I ran the next code (trans_matrix <- read_baskets("mytxtout.txt", sep = ";", info = c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))), I am getting an error message: "Warning message:
In read_baskets("mytxtout.txt", sep = ";", info = c("sequenceID",  :
  eventID not positive."